# Model relations not working when using queryBuilder methods in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I use `Laravel Relations` while using `Query Builders` ?

```
$Cars = User::find(1)->car; // works well and returns all cars

$User = User::where('username' , 'John')->get();
$Cars = $User->car; // doesn't work.
```

Any help.
thanks

**Solved**

```
$User = User::where('username' , 'John')->get();
```

Should Be

```
$User = User::where('username' , 'John')->first(); // to get an object instead of array
```

Comment: You have to make another eloquent model for making relationships. May I know if you are using another table for cars?

Comment: yes, cars is another table and model, with one to many relationship.

Comment: remember: get() returns a collection, first() returns the first model that is returned from get().

Comment: but you are asking about the Laravel Relations, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `::find()` method will return an instance of your model, which allows you to access relations and such that are setup on the model.

The `->get()` method will return an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` of results, even if there is only 1 row selected from the database.

Using the collection you can then loop through the results

```
$collection->each(function($model)
{
    // You can now access $model->cars
});
```

Alternativly you may use the `->first()`, `->last()` and `::find()` methods to return a single instance of your model which allows you to directly access relations.

```
$model = Model::where('foo', 'bar')->first(); // Returns first row from the database

$model->cars // Is now accessable
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have your Cars class all you have to do is to add method to your User class.

```
//add this method to your User class
public function cars()
{
    //since you'll be using many to many
    //you might use `user_cars` as pivotal table
    return $this->belongsToMany('Cars', 'user_cars', 'cars', 'cars');
}
```

You may call it using:

```
User::find(1)->cars()->get();
```